# Saving of captured images will leak malloc 48 bytes in strdup frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi guys I am working on an application in which I am capturing images and also recording video and my application works perfectly but when I using this code

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,@selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);
```

My application Received memory warning in malloc 48 bytes in strdup frame.

And I am using Xcode 4.3.3 with iOS 5.1.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (isPhoto == YES) {   
        viewForAll.hidden = YES;
        viewForDisplay.hidden = NO;
        isPost1 = YES;
        UIImage* image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0);

        UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(800,1000));
        [img1 drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 1000)];

        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        iView.hidden = NO;
        iView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        iView.image = smallImage;
        [img1 release];

    }
    else if (isVideo == YES) {
        viewForAll.hidden = YES;
        viewForDisplay.hidden = NO;
        isPost1 = YES;
        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
        videoPath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] retain];
        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
            NSLog(@"got a movie");
            NSURL *videoForURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
            videoData = [[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoForURL] retain];
            videoName = [[videoPath lastPathComponent] retain];
        }

        UITextField *txtFld;
        NSString *eventName;
        if ([appDelegate.eventArray count] != 0) {
            NSDictionary *dict = [appDelegate.eventArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else if (isZBar == YES){
        id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
        [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
        ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
        for(symbol in results)
            break;
        resultText = [symbol.data retain];      

    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear, did you actually receive a memory warning, or are you just leaking memory?

Comment: after leakage of memory my view will give the memory warning

Comment: Interesting, can you show how you are setting up "image"

Comment: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info in this method

Comment: Is UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum the only thing you're calling in that method?

Comment: no i am doing lots of thing in this method i am also resizing the image the also loading the video and try to sav that video also but facing same problem

Comment: You need to actually post all of the offending code or no one can really help you